# javascript for serving different image sizes

Tags: javascript, html

I found a script that detects viewport width:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/183715/Browsers-View-port-Width-Height-using-Javascript

I am adding this to the above-mentioned script:

```
if (viewportwidth < 321) {
    myimage.innerHTML=""
}   

if (viewportwidth > 320 && viewportwidth < 481) {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='320.jpg'>"
} 

if (viewportwidth > 480 && viewportwidth < 721) {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='480.jpg'>"
}

if (viewportwidth > 721 && viewportwidth < 1025) {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='640.jpg'>"
}   

if (viewportwidth > 1024) {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='960.jpg'>"
}
```

and using:

```
<body onload="fnGetWidthHeight()">

<div id="myimage">
</div>
```

Basically when the user opens the page, it will display a certain image depending on the viewport width, if the viewport is 320px or less - no image will be displayed.

This is my attempt to utilize 'responsive images'. Will this method load only the requested image - thus saving bandwidth? What are the pitfalls to this approach? I hope to add another function to determine the width of the 'myimage' div that will change the image based on a browser resize - is this possible. TIA

Comment: _“This is my attempt to utilize 'responsive images'”_ – there’s much better and more sophisticated solutions for that out there already (like f.e. Picturefill); I suggest you look into those, before dabbling in your own implementation that just leaves you with so many open questions as you are asking right now.

Comment: Hi CBroe - Thanks for the feedback. I am familiar with PictureFill though it has some minor drawbacks: "Users in non-supporting browsers that are unable to load or run the JavaScript will not receive a fallback image; they will receive alt text instead."

Comment: And what exactly do you think your solution as shown above will display to users without JavaScript …? Nothing either; but even worse (at least from an accessibility point of view) – they won’t even get an alt text shown, because there is not even an `img` element present _at all_ without JS.

Comment: Hi CBroe - Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this is a really great effort at making a web application better for your users, and I think it could be better fought if you consider utilizing a server to populate multiple image sizes. I'm certain that you are trying to keep the solution inside of your scope of knowledge, and I'd encourage you to take this challenge as a step to learning more.

Here are some of the pitfalls of this solutions

- You'll be hanging your content on loading the javascript when it is preferential to have your javascript loaded after your markup.
- Javascript and CSS read the width of the browser differently which means you'll need to do a ton of size and device testing (or simply accept less usability)
- A server will prevent you from manually resizing images, and you can simply focus on uploading large files to your server.
- Although unlikely, you may have users who won't use Javascript, and you need to consider what they will see.

As for your solution:

- Remove the individual if statements and simply use else if {}, since you'll only be using a single image depending on the users screen size.
- If you can't handle the server side programming, you can always manually enter in the background-image or content of the markup elements using css media queries. The good thing about this is you don't have to worry about the image hanging up through the implementation of javascript, and you'll have the exact device width.

Comment: Hi JosephMCasey
Thanks for the feedback. I am not familiar with server-side programming. I have used background-image with media queries but if I remember correctly - I did run  into a small problem

Comment: @user2301129 you will find far more problems when approaching this with Javascript. I think another wise piece of advice for this is to make sure you **debuff** any javascript that is using a windows event listener that triggers on window resize.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this method load only the requested image - thus saving bandwidth?

Yes, though the original code could be a bit optimized (see below)

> What are the pitfalls to this approach?

In terms of using it for what you used it in the example while knowing you can always rely on the width you're reading (think about Retina displays, for example, will the width you read provide the proper image?), there are no real pitfalls for people with enabled JS. It's a different story for most of the web crawlers and people with JS disabled...

> I hope to add another function to determine the width of the 'myimage' div that will change the image based on a browser resize - is this possible?

Yes, using almost the same approach and making use of the window `resize` event.

---

Slightly more readable snippet:

```
if (viewportwidth < 321) {
    myimage.innerHTML=""
}     
else if (viewportwidth < 481) {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='320.jpg'>"
} 
else if (viewportwidth < 721) {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='480.jpg'>"
}    
else if (viewportwidth < 1025) {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='640.jpg'>"
}    
else {
    myimage.innerHTML="<img src='960.jpg'>"
    // let's make this one the default
}
```

Comment: Hi Shomz - thanks for the feedback - yes, 'else if' is better. I did add:

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. I don't see the rest of your comment.

Comment: I waited too long. I did add window.onresize - seems to work OK on browser resize. I have tested this on OperaMobileEMU and mobiltest.me - seems OK. re Retina, etc - I need a reliable method to get css-pixel-ratios- any ideas?

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` works pretty nice for that.

Comment: Thanks again - I tried using https://github.com/tysonmatanich/GetDevicePixelRatio/blob/master/getDevicePixelRatio.js
It didn't work in mobiletest.me - but that could be their problem. Sometimes it works in OperaMobileEmu other times not - could be my 'custom' settings. And I am pretty sure that it wasn't working properly in Intel XDK. Time to retest these!

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure why you're having issues with it because it should work with pretty much anything these days (especially with anything that has a pixel ratio different than 1).

Comment: I ditched the js from github and just used: function PixelRatio() {
var value = window.devicePixelRatio
alert(value) } this works in IntelXDK but OperaMobileEmu gives 2.25 not 2

Comment: Well, there are different values there, not just 1 and 2.